# Using grep or awk

Tags: awk

I have lines in a log file which looks like

```
Oct 07, 2014 7:39:10 AM x.y.z

SEVERE: adding the post (STORY)  abcd = 495274900579805_10204277254604731 : a = 0 b = 0 c = 0
```

I would like to get the date and time from the first line and a=0 b=0 c=0 from the second line , how could i achieve this using grep and awk. Kindly help

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried? If you do awk, you usually don't need grep.

Comment: Hi @Anton 
I have used 
cat 2014-10-07_log* | grep -B 1 "495274900579805_1020427725460473" to get the above two lines from that i need to extract the items that i have mentioned from my previous post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk` version (you asked for awk)

```
awk '/AM|PM/ && NF--; /a =/ {print "a = "$(NF-6),"b = "$(NF-3),"c = "$NF}' file
Oct 07, 2014 7:39:10 AM
a = 0 b = 0 c = 0
```

---

The other version:

```
awk '/AM|PM/ && NF--; {n=split($0,a,"abcd");if (n==2) print "abcd"a[2]}' file
Oct 07, 2014 7:39:10 AM
abcd = 495274900579805_10204277254604731 : a = 0 b = 0 c = 0
```

Comment: Just awesome @Jotne worked like a piece of cake. Hope i start learning my basics on awk

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below grep command,

```
$ grep -oP '.*?(?=\s[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.\S+)|:\s+\K[^:]*$' file
Oct 07, 2014 7:39:10 AM
a = 0 b = 0 c = 0
```

**Update:**

```
$ grep -oP '.*?(?=\s[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+\.\S+)|\) *\K.*' file
Oct 07, 2014 7:39:10 AM
abcd = 495274900579805_10204277254604731 : a = 0 b = 0 c = 0
```

Comment: Hi @Avinash

It worked beautifully there is a small change in the data that has to be printed, can i get to print the second line like

abcd = 495274900579805_10204277254604731 : a = 0 b = 0 c = 0

and finally i need to push these lines to csv where date should be in first column , abcd in the second column , a in third and b , c following the subsequent columns in a csv . Kindly can you help me this